# how to add new values in sql python if data is already in database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a function to connect to a db and write data to it
The function accepts a list of dictionaries with data

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database="db_database",
        user='user',
        password='password',
        host='127.0.0.1',
    )
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor()


    get_data = "SELECT * FROM customer_new WHERE login_id = %s;"   # Availability check
    cursor.execute(get_data, (values_list['login id'],))
    
    last_item = cursor.fetchone()
    if last_item == None:
        '''If there are NO matches by login_id in the database, then it adds to the database'''

        sql = ("""INSERT INTO customer_new (login, telegram_id, orders, 
                        sum_orders, average_check, balance, group_customer, zamena, reg_date, bot_or_site, login_id) 
                        VALUES (%(login)s, %(telegram_id)s, %(orders)s, %(sum_orders)s, %(average_check)s, %(balance)s, %(group)s, %(zamena)s, %(reg_date)s, %(bot_or_site)s, %(login id)s);""")
        cursor.execute(sql, values_list)
    else:
        '''If there are matches in the database, then get the row id and update the data in it'''
        item_id_last = last_item[0]
        sql = ("""UPDATE customer_new SET (login, telegram_id, orders, 
                        sum_orders, average_check, balance, group_customer, zamena, reg_date, bot_or_site, login_id) 
                        VALUES (%(login)s, %(telegram_id)s, %(orders)s, %(sum_orders)s, %(average_check)s, %(balance)s, %(group)s, %(zamena)s, %(reg_date)s, %(bot_or_site)s, %(login id)s)""")
        cursor.execute(sql, [values_list, item_id_last])
    conn.close()
```

I need to write the received data to the database, if the received data is in the database, then they need to be updated.
How to implement it correctly?

Comment: You could look into sqls MATCH statement.

Comment: I kind of found a solution, use: INSERT ON CONFLICT